# How to work with checkbox and how to insert the records which is checked

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Here in my oracle apex report i am having 2 apex_items ,checkbox and textfield..

I need to insert the records which is checked in report if I have selected 5 checkbox then it should insert all the 5 records, currently only one record is getting inserting, please help..

SQL in interactive report query:

```
select  APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(1,pdcq.CHEQUE_NUMBER)"SELECT", 
pdc.CUST_NAME ,pdr.RECEIPT_NUMBER ,pdcq.INSTALLMENT,
pdcq.CHEQUE_NUMBER,pdcq.CHEQUE_AMOUNT, APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,null) Remarks
from pdc_customer pdc,pdc_receipt pdr,pdc_cheques pdcq
where pdc.CUST_ID=pdr.CUST_ID and pdc.CUST_ID=pdcq.CUST_ID and pdcq.status='Pending'  AND pdcq.RECEIPT_NUMBER=pdr.receipt_number
 and pdcq.APPROVER=NVL(SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'), USER)
```

Code

```
begin 
select NVL(SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'), USER) into v_user from dual; 
FOR I in 1 ..APEX_APPLICATION.G_f01.COUNT 
LOOP 
   FOR J in 1 ..APEX_APPLICATION.G_f02.COUNT 
   LOOP 
       UPDATE PDC_STATUS_HISTORY SET STATUS='Approved', 
          REMARKS=APEX_APPLICATION.G_F02(j), 
          APPROVED_DATE=sysdate ,
          APPROVED_BY=v_user 
          WHERE APPROVAL_LEVEL=1 and 
          CHEQUE_NUMBER=APEX_APPLICATION.G_f01(i); 
    END LOOP; 
END LOOP; 
end;
```

Comment: remove your comment. I edited your question, because that is what I guess you wanted

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're probably running into is the following. The array for the checkbox *only contains elements for the selected rows*, whereas the array for the text element will contain an element for *every* row. So the index for the selected rows will not match the text row if not all checkboxes are checked. To work around that you can add a 3rd column of type `APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN`

```
select  
  APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(1,pdcq.CHEQUE_NUMBER)"SELECT", 
  pdc.CUST_NAME ,
  ...
  APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,null) Remarks,
  APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(3,pdcq.CHEQUE_NUMBER) hidden_checkno
 from pdc_customer pdc 
      JOIN pdc_receipt pdr ON pdc.CUST_ID=pdr.CUST_ID
      ...
```

The process would then become:

```
BEGIN
  FOR I in 1 ..APEX_APPLICATION.G_f01.COUNT 
  LOOP 
   FOR J in 1 ..APEX_APPLICATION.G_f03.COUNT 
   LOOP 
     IF APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i) = APEX_APPLICATION.G_F03(j) THEN
       UPDATE PDC_STATUS_HISTORY 
          SET STATUS='Approved', 
              REMARKS=APEX_APPLICATION.G_F02(j), 
              APPROVED_DATE=sysdate ,
              APPROVED_BY=NVL(SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER'), USER)
        WHERE APPROVAL_LEVEL = 1 AND 
              CHEQUE_NUMBER = APEX_APPLICATION.G_f01(i); 
      END IF;
    END LOOP; 
  END LOOP; 
END;
```

Note1: The `SELECT FROM DUAL` is not needed, you can use that expression in your update statement directly.

Note2: Use ANSI JOIN style syntax instead of the *very very* old oracle syntax.