# Oracle APEX - Download selected files as zip - IR/IG checkbox selection

Tags: checkbox, download, oracle-apex, multi-select

I referred to this link [create a download zip button](https://apexcornies.wordpress.com/2020/04/04/create-a-download-zip-button-in-oracle-apex/) to download files in zip format in Oracle apex latest version 22.2. It is working fine without any issues but only concern is; it downloads all the files in one zip file. Whereas my requirement is to include a checkbox on a report (either IG or IR) and to download selected files in one zip file.

Below is the table I am referring to. Its from Oracle apex sample files upload and download.

```
select
    ID,
    ROW_VERSION_NUMBER,
    PROJECT_ID,
    FILENAME,
    FILE_MIMETYPE,
    FILE_CHARSET,
    FILE_BLOB,
    FILE_COMMENTS,
    TAGS,
    CREATED,
    CREATED_BY,
    UPDATED,
    UPDATED_BY
from EBA_DEMO_FILES
```

I tried searching over the internet and found few links pointing to APEX_ZIP, PL/SQL compress blob etc. But could not see any demo or working model similar to the link I provided above.

If anybody has working demo or blog,I request to share it. Many thanks.

Update: As suggested by Koen Lostrie, I am updating Page process code below:

```
DECLARE
  l_id_arr apex_t_varchar2;
  l_selected_id_arr apex_t_varchar2;
  var_zip blob;
BEGIN
  -- push all id values to an array
  FOR i IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F03.COUNT LOOP
    apex_string.push(l_id_arr,APEX_APPLICATION.G_F03(i));
    FOR j IN 1 .. APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP
      IF APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(j) = APEX_APPLICATION.G_F03(i) THEN
       -- push all selected emp_id values to a 2nd array
       apex_string.push(l_selected_id_arr,APEX_APPLICATION.G_F03(i));
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
    -- Create/clear the ZIP collection
    APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_OR_TRUNCATE_COLLECTION(
        p_collection_name => 'ZIP');
    -- Loop through all the files in the database
    begin
        for var_file in (select fi.filename, fi.file_blob, pr.project
                         from eba_demo_files fi
                         inner join eba_demo_file_projects pr on fi.project_id = pr.id
                         where fi.id in (SELECT column_value FROM table(apex_string.split(apex_string.join(l_selected_id_arr,':'),':'))))
        loop
            -- Add each file to the var_zip file
            APEX_ZIP.ADD_FILE (
                p_zipped_blob => var_zip,
                p_file_name   => var_file.project || '/' || var_file.filename,
                p_content     => var_file.file_blob );
        end loop;
    exception when no_data_found then
        -- If there are no files in the database, handle error
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'No Files found!');
    end;
    -- Finish creating the zip file (var_zip)
    APEX_ZIP.FINISH(
        p_zipped_blob => var_zip);
    -- Add var_zip to the blob column of the ZIP collection
    APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBER(
        p_collection_name => 'ZIP',
        p_blob001            => var_zip);
END;
```

Once page process is done, follow step 3 and 4 from the link provided in OP.

Below is the updated query:

```
select
ID,
ROW_VERSION_NUMBER,
PROJECT_ID,
FILENAME,
FILE_MIMETYPE,
FILE_CHARSET,
FILE_BLOB,
FILE_COMMENTS,
TAGS,
CREATED,
CREATED_BY,
UPDATED,
UPDATED_BY,
APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(1,ID) checkbox,
APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,FILENAME) some_text,
APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(3,ID) hidden_empno
from EBA_DEMO_FILES
```

Big Thanks to Koen Lostrie.
All credits goes to Koen Lostrie.

Thanks,
Richa

Comment: Looks like you're struggling to put  2 parts together. 1. how to work with checkboxes in interactive reports ( or interactive grids - note that that is very different) and 2. how to use selected values in checkboxes in a page process. The example in  the blog you mention uses an ajax callback process but that isn't necessary, it can also be done in a page process. There are multiple answers on how to handle checkboxes in an interactive report here on stack overflow (an on the internet in general), it shouldn't be too hard to find some, study those and apply them to the code for zipping files

Comment: @KoenLostrie thank you. I created DA with javascript expression to get selected row column values. Below is the code `var i, i_ids = ":", i_id,
model = this.data.model;
for ( i = 0; i < this.data.selectedRecords.length; i++ ) {
    i_id = model.getValue( this.data.selectedRecords[i], "FILENAME");
    i_ids += model.getValue( this.data.selectedRecords[i], "FILENAME") + ":";
}
apex.item( "P8_IDS" ).setValue (i_ids);` 
Now I am trying to write procedure to take these "P8_IDS" page item value as input parameter in my select statement where clause

Comment: I am considering filename only for example and for simple understanding. Since ID value is too long. To create procedure to download files, referring to same link as per OP.  [Create a Download Zip button](https://apexcornies.wordpress.com/2020/04/04/create-a-download-zip-button-in-oracle-apex/)

Comment: use id not filename - who cares it's long. It's the unique identifier. Why a dynamic action ? I would do it as follows (this is for interactive report, not interactive grid): determine what checkboxes are checked (see this answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73640961/i-want-to-make-a-list-where-when-selected-the-table-is-edited-according-to-wheth)) and then modify the select from ```EBA_DEMO_FILES``` to only pick the files for which the checkbox is selected

Comment: @KoenLostrie you are so talented. Thank you so much for the idea. I referred to your code and created page process and also combined step 2 from link from OP in the same page process. Later did Step 3 and Step 4 as per the link in OP. Now I am able to download selected files in zip format. Thank you thank you so much. I am providing page process code below so that it will be helpful for anybody who is looking for this solution. Also please let me know if there is much easier way to do it and get rid or branching and ajax callback. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Happy to help. Please do NOT post code in comments - instead add an updated to your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: @KoenLostrie I have one more question. I want to make checkbox header to check all. Do I need to use any plugin to achieve it or do you have any suggestions for the same?

Comment: You can probably do that using javascript but I don't have any code handy for that - googling "oracle apex checkbox select all" give me several results I'd use that as a start. If you're stuck please post a new question.

Comment: @KoenLostrie thank you. I got select all working now. However on the Interactive Report, if I hide these two columns `APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,FILENAME) some_text, APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(3,ID) hidden_empno` I get number error. Is there a fix for this? I do not want to show these columns in IR.

Comment: Added an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an answer to the last comment - the base question was answered in the comments. The question in the comment is "how do I include `APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN` columns in my report without hiding the columns".

When the columns are hidden in the report, they're not rendered in the DOM, so the values do not exist when the form is posted. That is the reason you're getting the error.

However, take a step back and check what `APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN` generates. Add a column of type `APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN` to the report and inspect the column in the browser tools. It generates an input element of type "hidden", so the value *is not shown in the report*. So to include the column in your report but not make it visible on the screen, just concatenate it to an existing other column:

In your case, with the select from the question that would be:

```
select
APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(3,ID) || APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(2,FILENAME) || ID,
ROW_VERSION_NUMBER,
PROJECT_ID,
FILENAME,
FILE_MIMETYPE,
FILE_CHARSET,
FILE_BLOB,
FILE_COMMENTS,
TAGS,
CREATED,
CREATED_BY,
UPDATED,
UPDATED_BY,
APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(1,ID) checkbox
from EBA_DEMO_FILES
```

Note that filename can also be in a hidden element.